# Need index for simple query please

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone suggest a good index to make this query run quicker?

```
SELECT 
    s.*, 
    sl.session_id AS session_id, 
    sl.lesson_id AS lesson_id
FROM 
    cdu_sessions s
INNER JOIN cdu_sessions_lessons sl ON sl.session_id = s.id
WHERE  
    (s.sort = '1') AND 
    (s.enabled = '1') AND 
    (s.teacher_id IN ('193', '1', '168', '1797', '7622', '19951'))
```

Explain:

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys  | key  | key_len | ref                | rows | filtered  | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | s     | NULL       | ALL  | PRIMARY        | NULL | NULL    | NULL               | 2993 | 0.50      | Using where
1  | SIMPLE      | sl    | NULL       | ref  | session_id,ix2 | ix2  | 4       | ealteach_main.s.id | 5    | 100.00    | Using index
```

cdu_sessions looks like this:

```
------------------------------------------------
id                            | int(11)
name                          | varchar(255)
map_location                  | enum('classroom', 'school'...)
sort                          | tinyint(1)
sort_titles                   | tinyint(1)
friend_gender                 | enum('boy', 'girl'...)
friend_name                   | varchar(255)
friend_description            | varchar(2048)
friend_description_format     | varchar(128)
friend_description_audio      | varchar(255)
friend_description_audio_fid  | int(11)
enabled                       | tinyint(1)
created                       | int(11)
teacher_id                    | int(11)
custom                        | int(1)
------------------------------------------------
```

cdu_sessions_lessons contains 3 fields - id, session_id and lesson_id

Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the table definition for `cdu_sessions`?  We might need to see this to render an answer here.

Comment: post a `EXPLAIN <query>` output also..

Comment: Have added to op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write the query so no type conversions are necessary.  All the comparisons in the `where` clause are to numbers, so use numeric constants:

```
SELECT s.*,
       sl.session_id,  -- unnecessary because s.id is in the result set
       sl.lesson_id
FROM cdu_sessions s INNER JOIN
     cdu_sessions_lessons sl
     ON sl.session_id = s.id
WHERE s.sort = 1 AND 
      s.enabled = 1 AND 
      s.teacher_id IN (193, 1, 168, 1797, 7622, 19951);
```

Although it might not be happening in this specific case, mixing types can impede the use of indexes.

I removed the column as aliases (`as session_id` for instance).  These were redundant because the column name is the alias and the query wasn't changing the name.

For this query, first look at the `WHERE` clause.  All the column references are from one table.  These should go in the index, with the equality comparisons first:

```
create index idx_cdu_sessions_4 on cdu_sessions(sort, enabled, teacher_id, id)
```

I added `id` because it is also used in the `JOIN`. 
 Formally, `id` is not needed in the index if it is the primary key.  However, I like to be explicit if I want it there.

Next you want an index for the second table.  Only two columns are referenced from there, so they can both go in the index.  The first column should be the one used in the `join`:

```
create index idx_cdu_sessions_lessons_2 on cdu_sessions_lessons(session_id, lesson_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without looking at the query plan, row count and distribution on each table, is hard to predict a good index to make it run faster.

But, I would say that this might help:

```
> create index sessions_teacher_idx on cdu_sessions(teacher_id);
```

Comment: How would this help given that that the OP is selecting _all_ columns from the `cdu_sessions` table?  Would MySQL even likely use this index?

Comment: Index will help to narrow the `row` count, not the columns. RDBMS will load fewer pages from disk to execute the query. It might use an index like this since there a part of the where clause is `s.teacher_id in (...)`.

Comment: Have amended op

Answer (score 1):

looking at where condition you could use a composite index for table cdu_sessions

```
create index idx1 on cdu_sessions(teacher_id, sort, enabled);
```

and looking to join and select  for table cdu_sessions_lessons

```
create index idx2 on cdu_sessions_lessons(session_id, lesson_id);
```

Comment: The order of columns in `WHERE` clause is the following: `(sort, enabled, teacher_id)`. 

I think that the composite index should be in the same order so MySQL can benefit from that index?

Comment: no @kav you want index selectivity.. teacher_id is a INT vs sort, enabled which are TINYINT meaning teacher_id  can have much more unique values which a index can filter out.. Whats why it's first in the index..  Besides the order in the WHERE does not matter MySQL's optimizer is smart enough to know `WHERE
   teacher_id IN(1, 2, 3)
 AND
   sort = 1 
 AND
   enabled = 1` and `WHERE
   sort = 1 
 AND
   enabled = 1
 AND
   teacher_id IN(1, 2, 3)` can use that [cdu_sessions(teacher_id, sort, enabled) index](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4R5fXTL2E7HBmUEU6CZc4n/0)